# Calculation within MYSQL Tables

Tags: mysql

I have some data in mysql and was wondering whether I can create a new table and then add some type of formula that can count existing tables? For example, I have a table called 'Reviews' which contains 150 rows. Can I have a separate table within mysql that can tell me there are 150 rows without me logging in to see this? Any help appreciated.

Comment: The following may help: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Comment: How do you propose to read from the separate table "*without logging in to see it*"?

Comment: If you want data from a database you need to log into it

Comment: All the Schema related information is Stored in [Infomation_Schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html)

Comment: At the moment, the MYSQL periodically produces a live XML feed. What would be very handy within this feed is live data showing me how many reviews etc are in the DB. So I was wondering if the calculations could be done within MYSQL itself and then added to my XML data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `VIEW` that contains the count and has other permissions than the table;

```
CREATE VIEW ReviewCount AS SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Reviews;
```

This view will have the read access of the *defining* user, and you can hide the underlying table from the other user, while he can still use the view to get the count.

The thing is, as far as the database is concerned, the other user still has to be logged in. If you want truly anonymous access, you'll have to wrap the database inside your own code, for example a web service.

EDIT: Your comment indicates that what you're looking for is simply a summary table of counts from a number of tables. In that case, you can simply create the view as;

```
CREATE VIEW test_count AS 
 SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reviews) reviewCount, 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM records) recordCount,
        ...
        ;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5cbc/1).